# Is it local.xml the right location for my layout update? Or should I create another file?

Tags: php, magento

I have added the following code in local.xml

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="cj_udo" template="cj/udo.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

on /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

Is this the right place, or should be separated?

What does it mean base folder? it means it applies to all themes and if I change theme it will continue working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who you are.

If you're a Magento system owner, or working on a specific system for a Magento system owner, `local.xml` is the right place for your layout updates.

However, if you're a module developer creating code you want to port to many different systems, then the correct thing to do would be

1. Create a new module
2. Add a layout update XML file (`namespace_module.xml`) to the `config.xml` for your module
3. Add this layout update XML file to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/namespace_module.xml`

Comment: can you please explain me point nr2, I already removed my code from local.xml and created a new file luisvalenciaaffiliatecj.xml, however I am not sure what code should I put on config, please check my screenshots. this is my config.xml file http://screencast.com/t/1drCqZxyOh and this is my new luisvalenciaffiliatecj.xml  http://screencast.com/t/tdeFrhW0lDM

Comment: got problems with it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331411/confused-about-adding-a-layout-update-in-my-new-module

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a theme, it is debatable but it is fine to update the layout file `local.xml` in your custom theme.

If you are working on a module, you should define a custom layout file, something like `namespace_module.xml` I prefer `namespace/module.xml` though. Even if you are theming, it is best to create a new module so you can define you custom xml anyway.

Under no circumstance should you directly modify core files, eg `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`. `app/code/core`, etc..

I think you need to research best practice development more, good start is http://magentotherightway.com/.